# mongodb statistic sub-document values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm very new to operating mongodb and could only use simple find() only. But I have a complex structure collection stored in mongodb which version is 3.2.15. And over 1000k records.

Main structure for statistic of the collection is like:

```
{
    "_id" : BinData(3,"oQsAvnL1X01YbXCd6X1q1A=="),
    "UserId" : BinData(3,"urrg10Znz0moqFize9js+A=="),
    ... (many unimportant nodes or arrays not included for statistic),
    "Pages" : [
        {
            "Url" : {
                "Path" : "http://www.aaaa.com/",
                "QueryString" : "?tipid=2C683459F4244C2181EB697DA32AB330"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For the Pages: may be empty or may be multi values for each UserId. For UserId: may be one record or may be many records.

My questions are: how could I could statistic following values:

1. How may different URLs(pages.url.path+pages.url.querystring) are in this collection totally?
2. How may different URLs(pages.url.path) for each user(group by UserId)?

Shall I use mapreduce? How to write the functions? Or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation pipeline as well. Assuming your collection name is `statistics`.

For first value:

```
db.statistics.aggregate([
    {$project: {"Pages": 1}},
    {$unwind: "$Pages"},
    {$project: {"Url": {$concat: ["$Pages.Url.Path", "$Pages.Url.QueryString"]}}},
    {$group: {_id: "$Url"}},
    {$count: "DistinctUrls"}
]);
```

For second value:

```
db.statistics.aggregate([
    {$project: {"UserId": 1, "Pages": 1}},
    {$unwind: "$Pages"},
    {$project: {"UserId": 1, "Url": "$Pages.Url.Path"}},
    {$group: {_id: {"UserID": "$UserId", "Url": "$Url"}},
    {$group: {_id: "$_id.UserID", "Pages": {$sum: 1}}}
]);
```

Although, given the dataset size Map-Reduce will perform better.

For first value:

```
db.statistics.mapReduce(function() {
    this.Pages.forEach(function(Page) {
        this.emit(Page.Url.Path + Page.Url.QueryString, true);
    });
}, function(key, values) {
    return true;
}, {
    out: 'distinct_urls'
});

db.distinct_urls.count();
```

For second value:

```
db.statistics.mapReduce(function() {
    this.Pages.forEach(function(Page) {
        this.emit(this.UserId, Page.Url.Path);
    });
}, function(key, values) {
    var newValue = [];
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        newValue = newValue.concat(value);
    });
    return newValue;
}, {
    finalize: function(key, values) {
        var pages = {};
        values.forEach(function(value) {
            pages[value] = true;
        });
        return Object.keys(pages).length;
    }
});
```